# Use pandas to implement data classification

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mKZ5.png)I have an excel file, the rows in it represent each day, a total of 365 days, each column represents a region, a total of 2310 regions, and the content is the temperature of each day. Now I want to use 1° as an interval. For example, 1°-2° is an interval. First, I obtain the 365-day temperature in a region, and then every 1° as an interval, and finally classify the 365-day temperature Enter the temperature range to get the most number of temperature ranges. Every area needs to do this kind of operation, how can I write this code, I use python.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mKZ5.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_excel('Step 1- Mapping SA2 to Climate Zone- Mean Temperature.xlsx',sheet_name='Daily Mean 2003-SA2')
df_value = df.drop(columns=['date'])
df_column = df_value.iloc[:,[0]]
i = 0
list_range = []
list_MFT = []
while i <= len(df_value.columns):
    df_column = df_value.iloc[:, [i]]
    for index, row in df_column.iterrows():
        for i in row:
            list_range.append(i)
            list_range.sort()
            for k, g in groupby(list_range, key=lambda x: (math.ceil(x) - 1)):
                # list_temp_range.append(list(g))
                a = '{}-{}'.format(float(k), float(k + 1)), len(list(g))
    i += 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This looks like a terribly non-Pandas (if you need to use a loop, you're probably doing something wrong), and non-Pythonic (e.g. that `while` loop is better served by `for i, column in enumerate(df_value.columns)`, etc.) approach.

Comment: Finally, you're not even using `a` for anything, so this code ends up doing a lot of work for nothing.